# Python post to URL from array/file

Tags: python

Working on a project where I can input an alfa-numeric=capital value directly into a url for example "DDAT705"

> https:xxxxxxxxxx/customers/ajax?salesno=DDAT705&key=1A2B3C4D&endpoint=taxonomy

And this will return me with information, If the alfa-numeric value is in the database it will return me with information if not it will return me a string that says "False" on the page.

I'm interested in fully automating the whole sequence, From reading a mass list of alfa-numeric combinations example "DDAT001" "DDAT002" "DDAT003" and so on up-to 999 for each combination then onto the next lot "DDAU701" and so on up-to 999 etc from a list of 35,000+ combinations inserting them in the middle of the URL one at a time to then saving the results from the "body" tag to a text or .CSV file.

Comment: Can you clarify the sequence a bit? Does in begin with `DDAAnnn` and end with `DDZZnnn`?

Comment: Does this web application already exist, and you just want to modify its behavior, or are you building the entire thing from scratch?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the context with the `url`. Are you using the `requests` library? Without seeing the code creating the requests, it's touch to recommend which direction to go. [mcve]

Comment: please don't vandalize your posts. To note that it's been answered, accept the existing answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples of how you could accomplish the first bit. The first generates the new `salesno` on the fly. The second generates a file containing every possible `salesno`, and an example of using that file. The second example illustrates a possible approach to using the `requests` module to construct your urls and use them.:

```
import requests
from string import ascii_uppercase

salesno_prefix = 'DD'
letters = ascii_uppercase
base_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx/customers/ajax'

# Generate them on the fly.
for letter in ascii_uppercase:
    for letter2 in ascii_uppercase:
        for number in range(1000):
            salesnumber = 'DD{}{}{:03d}'.format(letter, letter2, number)
            # Your code using the salesnumber.

# Create Permanent list.
salesnumbers = (['DD{}{}{:03d}\n'.format(letter, letter2, number) for number in range(1000) for letter2 in ascii_uppercase for letter in ascii_uppercase])

with open('sales_numbers.txt', 'w') as sales_file_out:
    for item in salesnumbers:
        sales_file_out.write(item)


# Use permanent list, for example. 
with open('sales_numbers.txt', 'r') as sales_in_file:
    salesnumbers = sales_in_file.readlines()
    for salesnumber in salesnumbers:
        print(salesnumber.strip())

        payload = {'salesno':salesnumber.strip(),'key':'1A2B3C4D', 'endpoint': 'taxonomy'}
        r = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
        print(r.url)
        print(r.text)
```